# Sublime Text 3 XML Indent Arrange attributes

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, auto-indent, xml-attribute, xml-formatting

In `sublime3` for XML formatting, i used `xml` indent plugin for auto indent, i use the shortcut `ctrl+K` `ctrl+F`. Here my question is the XML auto indent plugin also arrange the attributes in alphabetical order i want arrange only indent not attributes for this suggest any solutions for that please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it rearranges the attributes, there is an open issue for this:
 [github.com/alek-sys/sublimetext_indentxml/issues/59](https://github.com/alek-sys/sublimetext_indentxml/issues/59), which you can upvote so it could be taken in consideration faster.